# Java Swing program slows down over time in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ubuntu

So I made this solitaire game with Java Swing. I tested it on Windows and Mac OSX and it worked just fine. Then, I installed Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro, and when I run it from Ubuntu, it works but it gradually slows down, also slowing down the computer itself. I am using Java 8 OpenJDK, running from Eclipse (although running from the terminal results in the same problem).

Here is my code:

Solitaire.java

```
package solitaire;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

import cards.Card;
import cards.Deck;

public class Solitaire extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseInputListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6358510224557653758L;
    public static Solitaire app;

    public static Map<Card.Suit,Map<Integer,BufferedImage>> cardImg;
    public static BufferedImage backFace;

    public static int mx;
    public static int my;
    public static int dmx;
    public static int dmy;

    public static Deck draw_pile;
    public static Deck discard_pile;
    public static Deck[] center_pile;
    public static Deck[] ace_pile;

    public static Deck deckDragged;
    public static List<Card> dragged;

    public static boolean isDragged(Card card) {
        for (Card drag : dragged) {
            if (card == drag) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (mx >= 642 && mx < 721 && my >= 24 && my < 147) {
            draw();
            //repaint();
        } else { //if (mx >= 24 && mx < 103 && my >= 171 && my < 294) {
            for (int dn=0;dn<7;dn++) {
                Deck deck = center_pile[dn];
                boolean foundDragged = false;
                for (int cn=0;cn<deck.size();cn++) {
                    Card card = deck.card(cn); //deck.size()-cn-1);
                    if (foundDragged) dragged.add(card);
                    else if (!card.flipped) {
                        if (cn < deck.size()-1) {
                            if (mx >= dn*103+24 && mx < (dn+1)*103 && my >= cn*32+171 && my < (cn+1)*32+171) {
                                foundDragged = true;
                                deckDragged = deck;
                                dragged.add(card);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (mx >= dn*103+24 && mx < (dn+1)*103 && my >= cn*32+171 && my < (cn+1)*32+262) {
                                foundDragged = true;
                                deckDragged = deck;
                                dragged.add(card);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int dn=0;dn<4;dn++) {
                Deck deck = ace_pile[dn];
                if (deck.size() > 0) {
                    if (mx >= dn*103+24 && mx < (dn+1)*103 && my >= 24 && my < 147) {
                        deckDragged = deck;
                        dragged.add(deck.last());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (discard_pile.size() > 0) {
                if (mx >= 539 && mx < 618 && my >= 24 && my < 147) {
                    dragged.add(discard_pile.last());
                    deckDragged = discard_pile;
                }
            }
            //dragged.add(center_pile[0].first());
            dmx = mx;
            dmy = my;
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (dragged.size() > 0) {
            Card dragFirst = dragged.get(0);
            for (int dn=0;dn<7;dn++) {
                Deck deck = center_pile[dn];
                int s = deck.size();
                //s = s == 0 ? 1 : s;
                Card deckLast = deck.last();
                if (s > 0) {
                    if (dragFirst.rank+1 == deckLast.rank && dragFirst.red != deckLast.red) {
                        if (mx >= dn*103+24 && mx < (dn+1)*103 && my >= (s-1)*32+171 && my < s*32+262) {
                            for (Card card : dragged) {
                                deckDragged.cards.remove(card);
                                deck.add(card);
                            }
                            dn = 7;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (dragFirst.rank().equals("King")) {
                    if (mx >= dn*103+24 && mx < (dn+1)*103 && my >= (s-1)*32+171 && my < s*32+262) {
                        for (Card card : dragged) {
                            deckDragged.cards.remove(card);
                            deck.add(card);
                        }
                        dn = 7;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (dragged.size() == 1) {
                for (int dn=0;dn<4;dn++) {
                    Deck deck = ace_pile[dn];
                    Card deckLast = deck.last();
                    if (mx >= dn*103+24 && mx < (dn+1)*103 && my >= 24 && my < 147) {
                        if (deck.size() == 0) {
                            if (dragFirst.rank().equals("Ace")) {
                                deckDragged.cards.remove(dragFirst);
                                deck.add(dragFirst);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (dragFirst.rank-1 == deckLast.rank && dragFirst.suit.equals(deckLast.suit)) {
                                deckDragged.cards.remove(dragFirst);
                                deck.add(dragFirst);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (Deck deck : center_pile) {
                if (deck.last() != null)
                    deck.last().flipped = false;
            }
        }
        dragged = new ArrayList<Card>();
        deckDragged = null;
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        mx = e.getX();
        my = e.getY()-25;
        //repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mx = e.getX();
        my = e.getY()-25;
        //repaint();
    }


    public Solitaire() {
        super();

        BufferedImage cardSheet = null;

        try {
            cardSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("cards.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        cardImg = new HashMap<Card.Suit,Map<Integer,BufferedImage>>();
        Card.Suit[] suits = new Card.Suit[]{Card.Suit.CLUBS, Card.Suit.DIAMONDS, Card.Suit.HEARTS, Card.Suit.SPADES};
        for (int y=0;y<5;y++) {
            if (y < 4) {
                cardImg.put(suits[y], new HashMap<Integer,BufferedImage>());
                for (int x=0;x<13;x++) {
                    cardImg.get(suits[y]).put(x+1,cardSheet.getSubimage(x*79, y*123, 79, 123));
                }
            } else {
                backFace = cardSheet.getSubimage(158, 492, 79, 123);
            }
        }

        draw_pile = new Deck(cardImg, backFace);
        draw_pile.fill();
        draw_pile.flip();
        draw_pile.shuffle();
        discard_pile = new Deck(cardImg, backFace);
        center_pile = new Deck[7];
        ace_pile = new Deck[4];
        dragged = new ArrayList<Card>();

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) { ace_pile[i] = new Deck(cardImg, backFace); }
        for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
            center_pile[i] = new Deck(cardImg, backFace);
            for (int e=0;e<i+1;e++) {
                center_pile[i].add(draw_pile.draw());
                if (e == i) center_pile[i].last().flip();
            }
        }

        add(new Board());
        pack();

        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

        setTitle("Solitaire");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void main() {
        boolean playing = true;
        while (playing) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (draw_pile.size() > 0)
            discard_pile.add(draw_pile.draw().flip());
        else {
            draw_pile = discard_pile.flipCards().clone();
            discard_pile.empty();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        app = new Solitaire();
        app.setVisible(true);
        app.main();
    }
}
```

Board.java

```
package solitaire;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import cards.Card;
import cards.Deck;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6536587208518567333L;

    public Board() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(745, 702));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //center_pile starts at y=171
        for (int dn=0;dn<7;dn++) {
            Deck deck = Solitaire.center_pile[dn];
            for (int cn=0;cn<deck.size();cn++) {
                Card card = deck.card(cn); //deck.size()-cn-1);
                //if (dn == 0 && cn == 0 && card == Solitaire.dragged) System.out.println("equals");
                if (!Solitaire.isDragged(card))
//                  g.drawImage(card.disp(), dn*103+24+(Solitaire.mx-Solitaire.dmx), cn*32+171+(Solitaire.my-Solitaire.dmy), null);
//              else
                    g.drawImage(card.disp(), dn*103+24, cn*32+171, null);
            }
        }
        for (int dn=0;dn<4;dn++) {
            Deck deck = Solitaire.ace_pile[dn];
            g.drawRoundRect(dn*103+22, 22, 82, 126, 7, 7);
            if (deck.size() > 0) {
                if (Solitaire.deckDragged != deck)
                    g.drawImage(deck.last().disp(), dn*103+24, 24, null);
                else if (deck.size() > 1)
                    g.drawImage(deck.card(deck.size()-2).disp(), dn*103+24, 24, null);
            }
        }
        if (Solitaire.draw_pile.size() > 0) g.drawImage(Solitaire.backFace, 642, 24, null);
        if (Solitaire.discard_pile.size() > 0) {
            if (Solitaire.deckDragged != Solitaire.discard_pile)
                g.drawImage(Solitaire.discard_pile.last().disp(), 539, 24, null);
            else if (Solitaire.discard_pile.size() > 1)
                g.drawImage(Solitaire.discard_pile.card(Solitaire.discard_pile.size()-2).disp(), 539, 24, null);
        }

        if (Solitaire.dragged.size() != 0) {
            for (int i=0;i<Solitaire.dragged.size();i++) {
                Card card = Solitaire.dragged.get(i);
                g.drawImage(card.disp(), Solitaire.mx-40, Solitaire.my-16+i*32, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `cards` package and classes in it are not related to this issue.

Comment: Im no swing master but I think `while (playing) { repaint();  }` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I'm fairly new to swing, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Im not going try and provide an awnser to your question because theres no way to say that an awnser is correct or not. As it stands your question should be closed due to lack of information about the problem. I would guess that the loop is the source of the issue. Take a look at http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0 which seems to have some good information about game loops in Java.

Comment: Why does it need to constantly repaint?  If you really need this, you should consider using a Swing `Timer`, [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: But why would it cause a problem in Ubuntu and not Windows or Mac OSX?

Comment: Mostly luck.  Setting aside the fact that the underlying painting implementation of X-Windows is different from OS X and Windows, constant repainting is going generate a massive amount of repaint events, which will overwhelm the AWT event queue.  Since you're doing something you're not supposed to do, this is an "all bets are off" situation: Even if it "seems to work" on some platforms, it may well be a problem on even those platforms under some conditions (different video drivers, for instance).

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the explanation!